# Unity and using Generics to register interface

Tags: c#, generics, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I have an interface

```
public interface IFormBuilder<T,K> where T : Entity where K : Form
{
    K Build(T entity);
}
```

I want to be able to pass in an entity and have it return a `Form` object from the `Build` method (`Form` object is not a `Windows Form` object it is my own class)

It seems to register fine using the code

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(IDummyFormBuilder<,>), typeof(DummyFormBuilder<,>));
```

I inject the `IFormBuilder` into the constructor of a `FormProcessingService`

```
private readonly IFormBuilder<applicationEntity, Form> _formBuilder;

public FormProcessingService(IFormBuilder<applicationEntity, Form> formBuilder)
{            
    _formBuilder = formBuilder;
}
```

The problem is in declaring the `FormBuilder` class

```
public class FormBuilder<T, K> : IFormBuilder<T, K>
{
    public K Build(T entity)
    {
        return new Form();
    }
}
```

The error message I get is

> Error CS0314  The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the
>   generic type or method 'IFormBuilder'. There is no boxing
>   conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T' to 'Entity'.
>
> The type 'K' cannot be used as type parameter 'K' in the generic type
>   or method 'IFormBuilder'. There is no boxing conversion or type
>   parameter conversion from 'K' to 'SmartForm'.

Can anybody explain what is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your interface definition you have these generic type constraints:

```
where T : Entity where K : Form
```

When you implement the interface, these type constraints are not inherited automatically, so you need to declare them on your class as well:

```
public class FormBuilder<T, K> : IFormBuilder<T, K>
    where T : Entity where K : Form
{
    // your class code
}
```

This tells compiler, that the generic type constraints on class `FormBuilder` are compatible with the ones from `IFormBuilder` and they can be used together.

Even if matching constraints are use there is still one issue in your method declaration:

```
public K Build(T entity)
{
    return new Form();
}
```

Compiler complains here that there is no implicit conversion from `Form` to `K`. In order to fix that, there are 2 approaches you can take.

First approach is to convert `Form` to `K`, like this:

```
public K Build(T entity)
{
    return (K)(new Form());
}
```

Second approach can be used if your class `FormBuilder` has a constructor with no parameters. In this case you can add constraint `new()` to your class declaration and then you can create new form using `new K()`:

```
public class FormBuilder<T, K> : IFormBuilder<T, K>
where T : Entity where K : Form, new()
{
    public K Build(T entity)
    {
        return new K();
    }
}
```